# connect branch.io api or branch api to Jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas, api, jupyter-notebook, branch, branch.io

Unable to figure out how to connect branch.io api to jupyter notebook and see what data is there?
Since I'm very new to branch.io, not able to understand the documentation as well.
Can someone help me how to connect the same if anyone has done previousl?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
import requests
```

url = "https://api2.branch.io/v3/export"

payload = {
"branch_key": "xxxxx",
"branch_secret": "xxxx",
"export_date": "2023-02-20"
}
headers = {
"accept": "application/json",
"content-type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)

more information here.

https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/reference/requestdailyexport

Comment: You can formatt your code example either by inline it 1 tab or by putting 3 backticks before and after: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks